# SQL Server 2014-2016 Incorrect order by [nvarchar]

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

```
SELECT ItemNo FROM Stock Order By ItemNo Desc



   ItemNo
----------
1        3
2        2
3        1
4       10
```

I never paid attention to this before. The nvarchar type does the sorting of the field according to the first character .. I want to do it according to the whole word what should I do?

Comment: Store numbers in integer columns...

Comment: nvarchar columns

Comment: That's a poor table design. I said store integers in integer columns.

Comment: Sorry .. can be added at values like "A10"

Comment: Yes. A string type uses *string* sorting rules. Why is this surprising? Since you apparently have a mixture of numeric and non-numeric values in this column, can you *clearly* define what rules you wish to apply when a mixture of such values is present?

Comment: **Never**, ever store numbers in `varchar` columns.

Comment: Add A10 value to the sample data as well, and also specify the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sorting the column which is `varchar` type and if it in number form, then you can cast it into integer in `order by` clause.

**Query**

If in ascending or

```
select [ItemNo] from [Stock] 
order by cast([ItemNo] as int);
```

for descending order,

```
select [ItemNo] from [Stock] 
order by cast([ItemNo] as int) desc;
```

And another way,

**Query**

For ascending order,

```
select [ItemNo] from [Stock] 
order by len([ItemNo]), [ItemNo];
```

for descending order,

```
select [ItemNo] from [Stock] 
order by len([ItemNo]) desc, [ItemNo] desc;
```

**Note** : Suggesting you to store numbers in column type `INT`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ItemNo 
FROM Stock 
Order By CAST(ItemNo AS INT) Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

your column is nvarchar so it considering Numbers as a string and sorting it as alphabets
try casting like below

```
SELECT ItemNo FROM Stock Order By CAST(ItemNo AS INT) Desc
```

Here Official Information

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

But I recommend that you use Int Columns for Item No

If you have alpha Numberic values use this

```
SELECT ItemNo ,
        CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',ItemNo ) > 1 THEN
          LEFT(ItemNo ,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',ItemNo )-1)
        ELSE 
          ItemNo 
        END As alphabetical_sort, -- alphabetical sort
        CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',ItemNo ) > 1 THEN
          CAST(SUBSTRING(ItemNo ,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',ItemNo ),LEN(ItemNo )) as float)
        ELSE
          NULL
        END As Numeric_Sort
FROM dbo.Stock 
ORDER BY alphabetical_sort, Numeric_Sort
```

Comment: tnx. not only number